# Is there a pmatch equivalent of the which function in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I am using the following code to get the index of certain matches in the below matrix in R:

```r
      [,1]  [,2] 
 [1,] "t2"  "t2" 
 [2,] "t5"  "t5" 
 [3,] "t7"  "t7" 
 [4,] "t10" "t10"
 [5,] "t9"  "t9" 
 [6,] "t4"  "t4" 
 [7,] "t8"  "t8" 
 [8,] "t6"  "t6" 
 [9,] "t3"  "t3" 
[10,] "t1"  "t1"
```

```
searchstring<-c("t1","t2")
searchresult<-which(association[,1] %in% searchstring)
#The result is "10,1"
```

I need to be able to find partial matches.  For example, if I enter 't1' as the search string, I need the output to be '4,10'.  This is just example data here but in my real data all of the strings in the matrix will be unique but I will only have part of the string to search with so I need to search for just that part and return the row index of any that match the string just like which does for the full string.  Is there a function to do this in R?  I have tried to get pmatch to work but have not been able to.

Comment: Is searchstring always a single value, or do you want it to work over multiple? E.g.: `which(Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(searchstring, grepl, x=association[,1])))` or something like it will do everything together.

Comment: That works great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, which matches each member of the search strings to the columns so you can keep track of which element matches where. If this is unnecessary, you can `unlist` the result.

```r
lapply(searchstring, function(x) {
  which(!is.na(match(substr(association[,1], 1, nchar(x)), x)))})
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  4 10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
```

---

**Data**

```r
set.seed(3295269)
association <- matrix(paste0("t", 1:10)[sample(10)], ncol = 2, nrow = 10)

association
#>       [,1]  [,2] 
#>  [1,] "t2"  "t2" 
#>  [2,] "t5"  "t5" 
#>  [3,] "t7"  "t7" 
#>  [4,] "t10" "t10"
#>  [5,] "t9"  "t9" 
#>  [6,] "t4"  "t4" 
#>  [7,] "t8"  "t8" 
#>  [8,] "t6"  "t6" 
#>  [9,] "t3"  "t3" 
#> [10,] "t1"  "t1"

searchstring <- c("t1","t2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try `grep`

```
> lapply(paste0("^", searchstring), grep, x = association[, 1])
[[1]]
[1]  4 10

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

or `startsWith` + `unstack`

```
> unstack(as.data.frame(which(sapply(searchstring, startsWith, x = association[, 1]), arr.ind = TRUE)))
$`1`
[1]  4 10

$`2`
[1] 1
```